# How can I enter a formula that pulls data from a newly added sheet of an Excel workbook, not specified by number?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

My Excel workbook has a summary Recap sheet
followed by many sheets, each named for a different city. 
More cities (and sheets) are added over time, so I add more lines to the Recap sheet. I'm trying to create a macro to populate the cell in the new Recap line with the data from the newly added city sheet.

Within the macro, how can I enter a formula that pulls data
from the newly added sheet of the workbook
rather than from a specific sheet title or sheet number?

For example, my most recently added city (and sheet) was Boston,
but now I need to add several more cities.

Macro so far:

```
Sub AddToRecap()
'
' AddToRecap Macro
' Add new city info to Recap sheet
'

'
    Range("B39").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Boston!R[-30]C"
    Range("A40:C40").Select
End Sub
```

I've tried changing `Boston!`
to various permutations of `(Sheets.Count)` or `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select`,
and none of that has worked.

Comment: You need to get the name of the last sheet, then use that to generate the string for the formula. [This could be a starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995931/vba-get-name-of-last-added-sheet) an online search should yield more results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very rough and basic, this will yield the last worksheet name.

```
Sub LastSheetName()
    Dim wbkBook As Excel.Workbook

    Set wbkBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Debug.Print wbkBook.Worksheets(wbkBook.Worksheets.Count).Name
End Sub
```

The worksheet name is what you'll need to refer to it.

Revised Edit:

```
Function GetLastSheetName() As String
    Dim wbkBook As Excel.Workbook

    Set wbkBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    GetLastSheetName = wbkBook.Worksheets(wbkBook.Worksheets.Count).Name
End Function
```

Use this function, or assign it to a string variable in your code. In conjuction with Engineer Toast's answer/comment, you should get it working.

Note from Engineering Toast,

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='" & wbkBook.Worksheets(wbkBook.Worksheets.Count).Name & "'!R[-30]C"
```

Try this

```
Dim strLastSheetName as String

strLastSheetName = GetLastSheetName()

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='" & strLastSheetName & "'!R[-30]C"
```

Comment: I tried adding this to the beginning of my macro, but it didn't change anything. What should I change "Boston" to once I've added your string to the beginning?

Comment: @Megan `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='" & wbkBook.Worksheets(wbkBook.Worksheets.Count).Name & "'!R[-30]C"` Note that I wrapped the sheet name in single quotes `' '` in case it has a space in it.

Comment: @EngineerToast I got the error message "Can't execute code in break mode". I'm pretty new to macros... maybe I put your string in the wrong place?

This is what I have:

Sub AddToRecap()
'
' AddToRecap Macro
' Add new city info to Recap sheet
'
    Dim wbkBook As Excel.Workbook

    Set wbkBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Debug.Print wbkBook.Worksheets(wbkBook.Worksheets.Count).Name
'
    Range("B39").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='"
    wbkBook.Worksheets(wbkBook.Worksheets.Count).Name
    "'!R[-30]C"!R[-30]C"
End Sub

Comment: @Megan take out the Debug.Print, that outputs results to the Immediate window within the VBA IDE, sorry about that, I was showing how you can get the name of the last worksheet in a workbook. I'll edit my answer and try be a bit more detailed.

Comment: @njc thank you, that makes sense to me!
I added what you recommended, but unfortunately I still got the error message "Can't execute code in break mode". Did I forget something?

Comment: This is what I have now:
Sub AddToRecap()
'
' AddToRecap Macro
' Add new city info to Recap sheet
'
    Function GetLastSheetName() As String
    Dim wbkBook As Excel.Workbook

    Set wbkBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    GetLastSheetName = wbkBook.Worksheets(wbkBook.Worksheets.Count).Name
End Function
'
Dim strLastSheetName As String

strLastSheetName = GetLastSheetName()

    Range("B39").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='" & strLastSheetName & "'!R[-30]C"
End Sub

Comment: @Megan, off the top of my head, in the Excel VBA IDE, there should be a menu called, Run. OPen the menu, there's a menu item called, Reset (square blue icon), press it, see what it does. That supposed to reset break mode.

Comment: If a program (macro) fails part way through, VBA halts at the program line causing the problem. An error message (which you may not understand, that comes with experience) will appear in a pop-up box and, once you have dismissed that, the editor will highlight the line that has caused the failure. The editor is now in "break mode". Experienced users can use "break mode" to poke around to determine the cause of failure (eg a variable being given an inappropriate value earlier in the code). No further macros can be run until the editor leaves break mode. njc's comment tells you how to do this.

Comment: I got it to work! After resetting break mode, I researched the error message. Someone said: "Each Sub and Function statement must eventually be followed by an End Sub statement before the next Sub or Function statement." So I just moved the function statement before the Sub started (rather than having the function statement within the Sub), and that made it work! Thank you all so much for your help! :D

Comment: @Megan, great! One more small VBA IDE tip, right click the toobar, select Customize, select the Commands tab, in the Categories: list, select Debug, you'll see a command called Compile Project, add this to your toobar. Use this tool to find syntax hishaps, unfound references, stuff like that. Not perfect, but it is helpful.

Comment: @njc That sounds great, thanks for the tip! But I don't see Debug or Compile Project in my Categories list. Are you sure it's under Debug? I'm in Customize Ribbon > All Commands.

Comment: @Megan, it's in the VBA (Visual Basic) development environment (It's not in the Excel Workbook Ribbon). Right click the tool bar, select Customise from the context menu. In the Customize list, select Debug, on the right side list, Select Compile Project command to add it to the toolbar. It's a handy command button to have.

Comment: @njc Got it! I'm sorry, my mistake. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, if you want a pure Excel worksheet formula
to refer to a cell on another sheet,
the formula needs to contain the *name* of the referenced sheet,
one way or another. 
But, if you’re willing to use a VBA-enhanced formula, using a VBA *function,*
you can do something that may be more to your liking.

This function will let you access (read) a cell on another sheet
using the sheet number:

```vb
Function abs_ref(sheet_num, ref)
    abs_ref = Sheets(sheet_num).Range(ref.Address)
End Function
```

There’s an implicit `.Value` at the end of the assignment line. 
You can put an explicit `.FormulaR1C1` there if you prefer. 
At the risk of oversimplifying,
`.Value` will fetch the evaluated value from the remote sheet,
while `.FormulaR1C1`
will retrieve the unevaluated formula from the remote sheet
and evaluate it on the local sheet. 
I can explain more if you can ask a good question.

From here, it’s not really about VBA. 
If you want cell `B39` (on the current sheet) to reference `Boston!B9`,
where `Boston` is the 42nd sheet,
all you need to do is set `B39` to `=abs_ref(42, B9)`. 
If you want to do this from VBA, do

```
    Range("B39").FormulaR1C1 = "=abs_ref(" & Sheets.Count & ", R[-30]C)"
```